# convert a list of objects to a list of single lists

Tags: python

I have a question:
I have a list of nested objects that I managed to change it to this format:

```
converted_nested_list = [
    {"cmd_count": 2, "name": "jacky", "powered": 10},
    {"cmd_count": 9, "name": "madi", "powered": 26},
    {"cmd_count": 7, "name": "alisson", "powered": 77},
]
```

if you can just explain to me how can I converted to this format in a pythonic way:

```
wanted_format = {
    "person_names": ["jacky","madi","alisson"],
    "person_details":[
        {"label":"cmd_count", "stats":[2,9,7]},
        {"label":"powered","stats":[10,26,77]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you know upfront what all the types of labels will be?

Comment: yes the labels are fixed and the type is str

Comment: Why 'label' and 'stats' and not just a `dict` of `label: stat`?

Comment: the format is requered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `defaultdict` to group the labels and values, and then use that dict to create your final structure.

```
from collections import defaultdict

converted_nested_list = [
    {"cmd_count": 2, "name": "jacky", "powered": 10},
    {"cmd_count": 9, "name": "madi", "powered": 26},
    {"cmd_count": 7, "name": "alisson", "powered": 77},
]

label_stats = defaultdict(list)
for value in converted_nested_list:
    for label, stat in value.items():
        label_stats[label].append(stat)

result = {
    "person_names": label_stats["name"],
    "person_details":[ 
        {"label": label, "stats": stats}
        for label, stats in label_stats.items()
        if label != "name"
    ] 
}
```

Comment: can we avoid the nested loops

Comment: @MariaMoulinka You cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```py
wanted_format = {
    'person_names': [person['name'] for person in converted_nested_list],
    'person_details': [
        {'label': 'cmd_count', 'stats': [person['cmd_count'] for person in converted_nested_list]},
        {'label': 'powered', 'stats': [person['powered'] for person in converted_nested_list]}
    ]
}
```